# Persist cookies on page reload of Vue SPA

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I am creating a simple SPA with a Vue frontend and Python API using Flask. Currently, I have everything configured on my local machine (API running at localhost:5000 and Vue SPA accessible at localhost:8080). I am using [flask-jwt-extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/) to manage authentication using JWTs and am passing back the access and refresh tokens as cookies in the response to the Vue SPA.

Just about everything is working, the cookies are getting set in the browser correctly however after a page refresh the cookies disappear. I feel I am just missing something with my configuration but nothing I have tried has worked for me thus far. Any thoughts?

My jwt-extended config settings are below:

```
JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH = "/api/"
JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = "/api/"
JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = timedelta(minutes=60)
JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH = "/auth/refresh"
JWT_REFRESH_CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = "/auth/refresh"
JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES = False
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ['cookies', 'headers']
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
JWT_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY')
JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES = True
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE = False
```

And the code in my vuex action to make the request is here:

```
doLogin({ commit }, loginData) {
  const transport = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true
  })

  transport.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {
    ...loginData
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Brain fart, everything is working as expected (I hadn't actually tried to make an API call yet). The cookies just appeared to disappear upon a refresh because in the SPA I would be a `localhost:8080/` while the cookies were set to work for calls at `localhost:<port>/api/`, making a call to an endpoint at `/api/something` the cookies were passed correctly.